# Popen().communicate vs subprocess.check_output() vs Popen().stderr

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have been reading different implementations of error handling from `Popen` in Python, but I don't seem to understand how one is better than the other, since all approaches eventually do the job. I have a `subprocess.Popen` that calls a program, that will fail when a dll is missing from the host computer. So far I've been catching it with `proc.stderr.read()`, but I've also found other usages such as `string, error = proc.comminicate()` and `try: subprocess.check_output()`.
My current code is like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([join('tools', 'vr_hasher'), self.iv_1, self.iv_2, self.iv_3, self.iv_4, ts], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
error = proc.stderr.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
if error:
    print("STDERR:", error)
    raise Exception(error)
hash = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
if not hash:
    print("Couldn't Generate Hash")
    raise Exception("Couldn't Generate Hash. Please make sure that you have entered the correct IV Values.")
```

The code provided is for reference only and there aren't any issues with it (unless you find any, so please do explain).

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @kaya3 it appears so that the un-chosen answer does answer me. Thanks!